# How to get current day of week like monday etc and compare it in android

Tags: java, android, date

I have 7 different images of monday, tuesday, .... sunday. Now what i want to do is when screen open then current day image should be in different color.

I have tried with below code but not getting different color.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
Date d = new Date();
String dayOfTheWeek = sdf.format(d);

TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
textView.setText(dayOfTheWeek);
```

Now in textview, I am getting Thursday as today is thursday. Now i have given condition like below.

```
    imageViewMon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mon);
    imageViewTue = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tue);
    imageViewWed = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.wed);
    imageViewThu = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thu);
    imageViewFri = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fri);
    imageViewSat = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sat);
    imageViewSun = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sun);



    if (dayOfTheWeek == "Monday") {
        imageViewMon.setColorFilter(0xFFFF3D60);
    }
    if (dayOfTheWeek == "Tuesday") {
        imageViewTue.setColorFilter(0xFFFF3D60);
    }
    if (dayOfTheWeek == "Wednesday") {
        imageViewWed.setColorFilter(0xFFFF3D60);
    }
    if (dayOfTheWeek == "Thursday") {
        imageViewThu.setColorFilter(0xFFFF3D60);
    }
    if (dayOfTheWeek == "Friday") {
        imageViewFri.setColorFilter(0xFFFF3D60);
    }
    if (dayOfTheWeek == "Saturday") {
        imageViewSat.setColorFilter(0xFFFF3D60);
    }
    if (dayOfTheWeek == "Sunday") {
        imageViewSun.setColorFilter(0xFFFF3D60);
    }
```

But I am not getting the image colour as i want, nothing happens just text view shows today's day but i am not getting different colour in my image.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I notice they're all set to the same ColorFilter there.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, yes but i have used condition, so it will change only for current days, other will be set normal only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

switch(day) {
    case Calendar.MONDAY:
        imageViewMon.setColorFilter(0xFFFF3D60);
        break;
        ...
}
```

Comment: then how can i compare days and change image of my color.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int d = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
switch (d) {
    case Calendar.MONDAY:
        imageViewMon.setColorFilter(0xFFFF3D60);
        break;
        // ...
}
```

You have two problems in your code:

1. Comparing strings needs to be done with `equals()`, not `==`.
2. Depending on the locale, the user runs your app, it will never match, because 'Monday' is not 'Montag' or any other translation.

Answer (score 1):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

switch(day) {
    case Calendar.MONDAY:
        ...
}
```

And you must compare strings with `if(string1.compareTo(string2) == 0) { ...}`

Answer (score 0):

Question already answered but how can all of you use if or switch... Use array (or collection...) with desired values (strings, colors, whatever you want) and get number of the day, then just use the number as position in that array. This way you can switch just one array instead of rewriting all the long ifs/switches etc.